# Is there a way to use the printer cable USB on a modem to adapt to a LAN for a computer and improve ISP connection speed?

Tags: ethernet, lan, modem

Our modem ([ARRIS TM502G Telephony Modem](http://www.cablemodems.com/downloads/specsheets/TM502G.pdf)) only has one Ethernet port which has to connect to the router.

Is there a way to have an additional Ethernet cable adapted from the printer port on our modem to connect to a computer and increase speed?

The router has additional ethernet ports to run from that but the speed maxes out at 20 Mbps download and I'd like to have a way to get modem ethernet speed without having to buy a new one.

Answer (score 5):

### Nope.

#### On a very basic level, the USB ports on modems and routers are typically only used for USB printers or storage devices and cannot be used for other devices such as Ethernet dongles.

But that said, you are asking two things when you ask this:

> “Is there a way to have an additional Ethernet cable adapted from the printer port on our modem to connect to a computer and increase speed?”

So — as explained above — you really cannot add a USB dongle to that modem’s to give it another Ethernet port; they are mainly used for USB printers or storage devices.

That said, you end that sentence:

> “…to connect to a computer and increase speed?”

Speed is never determined by how many Ethernet connections come out of a modem. The speed you get from your ISP is the speed that comes out of that single Ethernet port on the modem.

And even if you were somehow to add another Ethernet port it won’t suddenly double the speed. The speed your ISP gives you is the speed you get.

That said, if you are using an [ARRIS TM502G Telephony Modem](http://www.cablemodems.com/downloads/specsheets/TM502G.pdf) that modem only supports DOCSIS 2.0 which has a maximum speed range of 20 Mbps to 30 Mbps max. So if you want more speed, you need to get a new modem that supports DOCSIS 3.0 or higher. And you — of course — if your plan with your ISP only gives you 20 Mbps, simply upgrading the modem won’t matter: You will only get 20 Mbps.